# Share File via Email in Windows Phone Mango

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created on application which creates a file in isolated storage . Now i want to share it via email. Is there any option by which i can do it . I have tried Email Launcher , but it does not have any option to add attachment . 
If anyone can help me i will be grateful . Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to reach it via email. In my case, I uploaded it to Skydrive as an alternative.

Comment: it means cloud is only the way to share files.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way I found for sharing a file is via any sort of cloud service. Unfortunately, email file attachment is not supported so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EmailComposeTask` does not support attachments. This means that the only way you can send emails with attachements is via a separate, external service.
There are numerous third party email services which can let you send email with attachments or you can send them from your own web based task.
Alternatively you could share files via a file transfer service (dropbox, skydrive, etc.)